# Filter entity using a string array is not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I've researched and found that I use .Contains on the array to filter an entity, but my resulting list is empty what is wrong?

```
public List<Order> GetOrderstoShip()
    {
        var shipvia = new string[] { "UPS", "FED", "EX", "USP" };
        var orders = db.Orders.Where(
            x => x.VOID != "Y" && x.GONEDATE == "")
            .ToList();
        var exporders = orders.Where(
            x => shipvia.Contains(x.SHIPVIA.ToUpper())
            ).ToList();
        // Problem: exporders contains 0 items
        // My database field contains the following:
        // FEDEX, UPS, USPS, FEDEX GND, FEDEXGND
        // And, I made sure orders has a list of 900+ items
        return exporders;
    }
```

New Development: I went into my DB and edited one record.  I set the ShipVia field exaclty to UPS (previously it was UPS GND) and I got one item back in exporder.
That means the .Contains is exact match.  So how do I get it to do something similar to the SQL Like?

I thought the whole point of using contains was that is does partial match.

Comment: whats db.Orders? whats the result set for orders? whats shipvia?

Comment: Plugging in a mock collection of `orders` with valid items the query returns the expected items for me. I can't repro the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: db.Orders is a table in my database, the DB query returns 900+ records into the list orders which is then filtered for shipvia to create exporders, but that is where it fails.

Comment: JSteward: that is discouraging, that is why I posted here; it looks like it should work but it's not

Comment: Is it possible the `SHIPVIA` values contain trailing whitespace? I also note that you could do all that in one query and it would be MUCH faster since the filtering would be done on the SQL side:  `db.Orders.Where(x => x.VOID != "Y" && x.GONEDATE == "" && shipvia.Contains(x.SHIPVIA.ToUpper())).ToList();`

Comment: did you try using .TRIM() method ?

Comment: Stanley, that is how I started, all in one query but since it didn't work, I split it to troubleshoot.  My first query works and returns 900+ items

Comment: Yes, I used Trim() but it did not help

Answer (score 0):

Just a take a stab. You might have white space in your database table. You can try to trim the results first.

```
shipvia.Contains(x.SHIPVIA.Trim().ToUpper())
```

I would suggest doing this filter before the results are returned. This will speed up the database query time.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use a work-around since I only had three strings to check for, I expanded my filter by using or... not the most elegant but it lets me continue with my project!

If anyone figures out why the .Contains is not working, please let me know...

```
public List<Order> GetOrderstoShip()
    {
        var shipvia = new string[] { "UPS", "FED", "EX", "USP" };
        var orders = db.Orders.Where(
            x => x.VOID != "Y" && x.GONEDATE == "" && (
            x.SHIPVIA.Contains("UPS") ||
            x.SHIPVIA.Contains("FED") ||
            x.SHIPVIA.Contains("USP"))
            ).ToList();

        var exporders = orders.Where(
            x => shipvia.Contains(x.SHIPVIA.Trim().ToUpper())
            ).ToList();

        // Problem: exporders contains 0 items
        // My database field contains the following:
        // FEDEX, UPS, USPS, FEDEX GND, FEDEXGND
        // And, I made sure orders has a list of 900+ items
        return orders;
    }
```